# Xcode 6.4 iOS Simulator not working

Tags: ios, xcode6

First I tried to set up the simulator in Window -> Device, but after I clicked the create button the Xcode just stop responding.

Then I tried Xcode -> Open Developer Tool -> iOS Simulator. This time the simulator icon did show up in dock but it just kept jumping there and I have to force quit it.

Any suggestion?

Comment: just try it with a project

Comment: @StefanScoarta : but the problem is there is no simulator option under the drop down menu next to run/stop button, so I can't run the project in the simulator

Comment: you have to add the simulators..Click on Xcode. Hover to Open Developer tools and select iOS Simulators. After Simulator Opens. Click on Hardware and Manage Devices And Add the devices by clicking + button at the bottom

Comment: @Rajan : As I mentioned above I did that but the iOS simulator didn't open. it just kept jumping and i have to force quit it

Comment: May be a slow ram . GIve it some time or do a fresh install.

Comment: Resintall xcode,and delete all file Xcode has before you install it

Answer (score 0):

I closed Xcode and the simulator, went to ~/Library/Preferences, deleted the preferences file for Xcode and restarted Xcode. After that the simulator started again.

I am using Xcode 7.1 though.